# Windows Error logs codes

Tags: windows-server-2003, logging

In windows system error logs I see many error codes like 11, 9, 5... I need to know what are the reasons for these errors and how to troubleshoot them. Also every time this error occurs in the description it has something like device ....\adpu320A**2**. I know that adpu320A is the SCSI card but what is this 2 after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mostly use EventID.net to check event log entries, have you used EventID.net already?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far too general and there are so many possible error codes, many of them device specific, that it's just not possible to hand you that information ready to use. You need to put some effort in to help yourself.

When you view those event log entries there's a link for more information. Start by clicking on that. It won't always produce the information you need but it's a start.

Another thing you can do is to Google for the event ID and error codes.

After trying those things, if you still have a question about a **specific** error ask that question.

Comment: The error code that I see mostly is 11. I tried googling already and eliminated the possible causes like driver and bios update. But still the problem is there. I posted it here to see if I have missed possible causes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the error codes written to the event log are internal to the application, process, program, service, technology, product that generates the events.

My own applications sometimes write to the Windows Event Log. The first kind of thing i want to log is called:

- Event ID 1

as i add things, i keep adding numbers; maybe i mix it up, or skip some:

- Event ID 1337
- Event ID 69
- Event ID 10404

There is no documentation for these events, except for when users report error. i ask them for the codes, search my source code, and try to figure out what happened.

But i think you are limiting yourself to only Microsoft products, and probably only products created by the Windows group. i think you want documentation for all possible event id codes that can be generated by all Windows products.

Such a comprehensive singular list does not exist. So use [eventid.net](http://eventid.net).

Comment: What you describe for your own applications shows extremely poor management and understanding. This is hated equally by admins and users. If we give you an error code for your software you should be able to instantly look that up in the documentation and then explain to us what caused it. The only reason to go back to the source code should be to fix the problem.